# What is "Preview: Ubuntu Pro for Desktop" under Livepatch in Software & Updates?

Tags: updates, canonical-livepatch

I opened the Software & Updates app and under Livepatch, I saw this new message:

[image]

(The "new message" is in the big blue box)

I want to know what this is. I clicked on the link, logged into my "Ubuntu account" and I see a screen that says things about free personal tokens and "stuff." Screenshot:

[image]

(I replaced the token with "xxxxxx" because although I have no idea what this whole thing is, it's called a "token" so...yeah)

What is this whole "Preview: Ubuntu Pro for Desktop" thing and what can I do with this "token"?

In case it automatically install security updates, how is it different from the existing "unattended upgrades" feature?

I can't find anything on the internet because it seems new.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi this would probably be Ubuntu Server 20.04 and newer, as I'm also seeing this on all of my servers today 

Comment: Yay! A new programme to get automatic security updates! Um, don't we have one now?

Comment: @matigo It shows up in Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 as well.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes this is 20.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It shows in 22.04 _jammy_ desktop as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu Pro (https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro) is a Canonical product for commercial and enterprise cloud customers. It includes Ubuntu Advantage support (https://ubuntu.com/advantage) among other paid features. Since we are not Canonical sales staff, I won't detail the differences -- the links have all you need.

There is no free tier of Ubuntu Pro. However, there is no magician behind the curtain: The repositories and packages are the same as regular Ubuntu. Opinion: It seems a *convenience* product for folks with a budget and lacking time.

It is a paid product, so we do not provide support for it here.